# What is a minimal, complete example of pagination in Kohana 3.2?

Tags: php, pagination, kohana-3.2

I found much information about pagination in Kohana 3.2 but most of it is scattered across forum comments and blog posts with no single complete source to refer to.

(note: I intended to self answer this question)

Comment: This is not a search an example for me type of site. Please take a look in the FAQ.

Comment: @hakre I intended to self-answer this question since I spent a couple of hours in this issue when I thought I could've solved it in a few minutes. That's why I didn't add more details in the question. I'm sorry if it looked like I was expecting people to do the work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Download the pagination module from https://github.com/kloopko/kohana-pagination (pagination was removed from Kohana 3.2, so this is an adapted module).
2. Install the module in modules/pagination.
3. Add the module in bootstrap.php:

   ```
   Kohana::modules(array(
       // ... other modules ...
       'pagination' => MODPATH.'pagination'
   ));
   ```
4. Copy the configuration file from modules/pagination/config/pagination.php to application/config/pagination.php.
5. Add the following actions to your controller:

   ```
    public function action_index() {
        // Go to first page by default
        $this->request->redirect('yourcontroller/page/?page=1');
    }

    public function action_page() {
        $orm = orm::factory('your_orm');

        $pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
            'total_items' => $orm->count_all(),
            'items_per_page' => 20,
            )
        );

        // Pass controller and action names explicitly to $pagination object
        $pagination->route_params(array('controller' => $this->request->controller(), 'action' => $this->request->action())); 
        // Get data
        $data = $orm->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->items_per_page)->find_all()->as_array();
        // Pass data and validation object to view
        echo View::factory('yourview/page', array('data' => $data, 'pagination' => $pagination));
    }
   ```
6. Create yourview/page as follows:

   ```
   <?php
   foreach($data as $item) {
       // ...put code to list items here 
   }

   // Show links
   echo $pagination;
   ```
7. Modify application/config/pagination.php according to your needs. I had to change the `'view'` parameter to `'pagination/floating'` which displays ellipses (...) when the list of pages is too large, unlike the default `'pagination/basic'` which lists all pages regardless of length.

Comment: It would be better to use shadowhand's pagination module as he is unofficially supporting it: https://github.com/shadowhand/pagination

Answer (score 1):

Pagination wasn't originally working/supported in Kohana 3.2. Luckily, somebody has updated the module and you can get the code at https://github.com/kloopko/kohana-pagination